# Autofac, unit-testing, C# - Difference between Autofac Moq and FakeItEasy integration package

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, autofac

Can anyone help me differentiate between  Autofac Moq and FakeItEasy integration packages? 
My demo project uses Autofac for its dependencies. I want to change my unit test cases also to use Autofac Moq/FakeItEasy integration project. I am currently using Autofac MOQ

I was referring link: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/moq.html helpful but I couldn't run my test successfully.

In the example below IDAL and IDATE are my dependencies and IAGE is a parameter to my unit test function CalculateMatruity(age).

Questions:

1. Unit test is not taking my fake parameters IDAl, IDATE.
2. Also, can any please advise how to pass parameters to the unit test function.
3. Am I passing the parameter correctly my instantiating a New person() object?

my sample unit test is:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGenericHelper()
{
    //arrange
    using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
    {

        mock.Mock<IDAL>().Setup(x => x.GetMaturityConfiguration()).Returns("0=Child|13=Teen|18=Adult");
        mock.Mock<IAge>().Setup(x => x.Birthdate).Returns(DateTime.Parse("1987-06-16"));
        mock.Mock<IDate>().Setup(x => x.Date).Returns(Convert.ToDateTime("2000-01-01"));

        var sut = mock.Create<GenericHelper>(); 

        String expected = "Teen";

        Person age = new Person();
           age.Birthdate = DateTime.Parse("1987-06-16"); 

        //act
         //  mock.Provide<IGenericHelper, GenericHelper>(new NamedParameter("AgeObj", DateTime.Parse("1987-06-16")));

        String actual = sut.CalculateMatruity(age); 

        //assert
        mock.Mock<IDAL>().Verify(x => x.GetMaturityConfiguration());
        mock.Mock<IAge>().Verify(x => x.Birthdate);
        mock.Mock<IDate>().Verify(x => x.Date);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Previously my test was:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGenericHelper()
{
    Person age = new Person();
    age.Birthdate = DateTime.Parse("1987-06-16");     
    String expected = "Teen"; 

    DateTime FakeDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2000-01-01");
    String fake = "0=Child|13=Teen|18=Adult";

    FakeDate DateHelperObj = new FakeDate(FakeDate);
    FakeAgeDAL fakeObj = new FakeAgeDAL(fake);

    GenericHelper GenericHelperObj = new GenericHelper(fakeObj, DateHelperObj);
    String actual = GenericHelperObj.CalculateMatruity(age);

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}


Function GenericHelper looks like below:

 public class GenericHelper : IGenericHelper
    {
        private IDAL _DAL;
        private IDate _Date;

        public GenericHelper(IDAL DAL, IDate Date)
        {
            _DAL = DAL;
            _Date = Date;
        }

        public GenericHelper()
        { }
        public String CalculateMatruity(IAge AgeObj)
        {

           String Maturity = "", AgeConfiguration;

            //DateTime Now = DateTime.Now;

           IDAL dalObj = _DAL;
           IDate dateObj = _Date; 

            /*start */

                //using (var container = UATContainer.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
                //{
                    AgeConfiguration = dalObj.GetMaturityConfiguration();
                    Int64 Age = dateObj.Date.Year - AgeObj.Birthdate.Year;

                    //AgeConfiguration = container.Resolve<IDAL>().GetMaturityConfiguration();
                    //var _d = container.Resolve<IDate>().Date.Year;
                    //Int64 Age = _d - AgeObj.Birthdate.Year;      /* Using autofac approach */    

            var config = AgeConfiguration.Split('|').Select(s => s.Split('=')).ToDictionary(c => c[1], c => int.Parse(c[0]));

            if (Age >= config["Child"] && Age < config["Teen"])
                Maturity = "Child";
            else if (Age >= config["Teen"] && Age < config["Adult"])
                Maturity = "Teen";
            else if (Age >= config["Adult"])
                Maturity = "Adult";
            else              
                Maturity = "Inapproriate to calculate age,verify the DOB";

                //}
                /*end */
            return Maturity;
        }

    }
}
```

Correct test results:

```
public void TestGenericHelperAutofacFakeItEasy()
        {  
            using (var fake = new AutoFake())
            {
                A.CallTo(() => fake.Resolve<IDAL>().GetMaturityConfiguration()).Returns("0=Child|13=Teen|18=Adult");
                A.CallTo(() => fake.Resolve<IDate>().Date).Returns(Convert.ToDateTime("2000-01-01"));
                var sut = fake.Resolve<GenericHelper>();
                String expected = "Teen";
                Person age = new Person();
                age.Birthdate = DateTime.Parse("1987-06-16");

                String actual = sut.CalculateMatruity(age);

                A.CallTo(() => fake.Resolve<IDAL>().GetMaturityConfiguration()).MustHaveHappened();
                A.CallTo(() => fake.Resolve<IDate>().Date).MustHaveHappened();
                Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
            } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Question 1

**Update**:
Using your test and class, the only problem I see is your creation and `Verify` of `IAge`. The variable isn't used or needed. You never said how your test failed. Does it fail with

```
Test 'AutofacMoq.Class1.TestGenericHelper' failed: Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.Birthdate
No setups configured.
No invocations performed.
```

? If so, all you should need to do is remove the `mock.Mock<IAge>` setup and verification.

#### Question 2

I don't use MSTest, and I've not tried this, but I trust Dror Helper's assessment and would look at his post [MSTest V2 – First impressions](https://helpercode.com/2016/08/10/mstest-v2-first-impressions/), in which he describes a method whereby you can write a test that looks like

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(1, 2, 3)]
[DataRow(2, 2, 4)]
[DataRow(3, 2, 6)]
[DataRow(5, 2, 7)]
public void RowTest(int a, int b, int result)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(result, a + b);
}
```

#### Question 3

You appear to be filling in the property on the `Person` object correctly, but it really depends on how your `Person` class is defined. I made a guess, which you can see above.

#### Question 0

I use neither, but as far as I know, Autofac.Extras.Moq and Autofac.Extras.FakeItEasy differ in that they use different mocking frameworks to provide their fake objects. Personally, I'd try out Autofac.Extras.FakeItEasy, but that's due to my familiarity with FakeItEasy. I've no reason to believe one solution is better than the other.

Out of curiosity, I rewrote the test using AutoFaq.Extra.FakeItEasy and it came out like this, and also passed, all with the same auxiliary classes and interfaces I used above:

```
using (var fake = new AutoFake())
{

    A.CallTo(() => fake.Resolve<IDAL>().GetMaturityConfiguration()).Returns("0=Child|13=Teen|18=Adult");
    A.CallTo(() => fake.Resolve<IDate>().Date).Returns(Convert.ToDateTime("2000-01-01"));

    var sut = fake.Resolve<GenericHelper>();

    String expected = "Teen";

    Person age = new Person();
    age.Birthdate = DateTime.Parse("1987-06-16");

    String actual = sut.CalculateMatruity(age);

    //assert
    A.CallTo(() => fake.Resolve<IDAL>().GetMaturityConfiguration()).MustHaveHappened();
    A.CallTo(() => fake.Resolve<IDate>().Date).MustHaveHappened();
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: 1. The reason I used Fake IAGE was, i wanted to pass it as a parameter but not intended to fake it If I want to pass it as parameter should be passing a a object instance as I am doing currently?

Comment: 2. The reason I was using normal class/interfaces was. I understand that Autofac takes care of everything and we dont need to pass fakes, it can create dummy's when required. The main use of Autofac I think is it takes care of IOC dependency injection and with Autofac MOQ framwork it also creates MOQ objects. My GenericHelper is bit different. I replaced constructor inject as follwoing:

Comment: My GenericHelper is bit different. I replaced constructor injection using Autofac build container, registered my services.                                                  Yes, I am using all interfaces and are public

Comment: I have added my GenericHelper function in the question. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I've updated my answer for question 1. If this doesn't help, I suggest debugging into the test to see what's going wrong - are the fakes you expected not being supplied? Do they act differently than you want?
If nothing else, you could describe the actual failure you have.
Alternatively, if you can supply a small but complete solution, I can take a deeper look.

Comment: Hi Blair Conrad, Thank you for your response. I have updated my executable tests in the question.Tests are now running fine. Only thing was I have a verify statement initially which was not part of the process and it dint like.